# Как задать значение таймера QTimer в часах?

Tags: qt, c++

Я делаю программу "Будильник" и для этого собираюсь использовать класс QTimer. QTime задает интервал в миллисекундах и соответственно числа, задаваемые объекту QTimer, получаются длинными. Мне необходимо будет задавать интервал в часах, а может и днях. Если другой какой-нибудь вариант задавать числа более укрупненных размеров?

Comment: Действительно, int-a в миллисекундах хватит недели на две.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я думаю, что Вы прекрасно понимаете, что заводить таймером будильник на несколько дней вперед как то неестественно. У многих за этот период компьютер успеет перезагрузиться сотню раз.

Обычно делают так. Ставят таймер на час и каждый час проверяют следующие часовые метки, когда нужно сработать. Если на протяжении текущего часа их не будет, то ничего и делать не нужно. Если же на протяжении часа должен сработать будильник, то заводим дополнительный таймер, но на несколько минут раньше положенного. А когда он сработает, то уточним время и сработаем когда нужно.

Здесь есть несколько ситуаций.

- пользователь может завести несколько будильников на текущий час. Нужно будет отобрать самый ранний и обработать его. Потом  - следующий. То есть, правильно отсортировать.
- пользователь может в любой момент добавить/удалить/отредактировать. Соответственно, нужно пересчитать все таймеры.

Многие операционные системы предоставляют интерфейс к подобному функционалу - можно просто задать время и система сама вызовет callback. В этом случае задача сводиться только к правильной сортировке будильников.

Comment: Т.е. у системы может быть API для подобных задач? Я работаю в Mac OS. А callback - это функция, срабатывающая при наступлении времени?

Comment: У систем есть подобное апи. Оно точно есть у андроида. В линукс (да наверное и в маке) есть возможность использовать сигнал SIGALARM (не нужно путать с сигналами Qt). Но не думаю, что для Вас они будут лучше Qt таймеров.

Но в линуксе есть cron и ему подобные утилиты. Возьмите [сорцы](http://opensource.apple.com/source/cron/cron-35/crontab/crontab.c) от Apple и посмотрите как оно сделано. 

Я рекомендую делать программу из двух частей - одна консольная, которая будет демоном висеть в памяти, а вторая на Qt с красивым GUI для пользователя.

Comment: Если говорить о Linux (не знаю, есть ли аналоги в MacOS), то рекомендую почитать `man 2 timer_create` и `man 2 timerfd_create` (второй может быть даже удобней для программирования) и SEE_ALSO в них.